# How to make an Image.asset() to fit a SizedBox() in Row?

Tags: flutter, dart

Having a card (see image below)
[Figma Info card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Opu.png)
All I need to do is to reach this UI but look what I've got:
[My Info card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOSLb.png)

As you can see the image is not fitted, however I created a SizedBox with needed width and heigth, child FittedBox, which has its own child Image.asset but it's not fitted.
DevTools say that the SizedBox itself has 100x100(which is to be as expected) but the Image is not:(

So could you guys suggest me any possible solution or idea?
Appreciate any answer:))

I've tried to put it in Expanded but the Column with Text begins to overflow, I've also tried to create a Container() with ImageDecoration but this is not working as well.

[This is the image I need to fit (in case someone wants to try)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1p0H.png)

Here is the code of my InfoCard() widget:

```
class InfoCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String heading;
  final String description;
  const InfoCard({super.key, required this.heading, required this.description});



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 157.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        color: ColorConstants.kBackgroundSecondary,
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            child: FittedBox(
              child: Image.asset(
                '/images/info_card_icon.png',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 20.0),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  heading,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,`
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Text(
                  description,
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .bodySmall!
                      .copyWith(color: ColorConstants.kText),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After @CCP suggestion to remove FittedBox and set Image.asset fit = BoxFit.cover DevTools show me 100x100 image size.
[WIth FittedBox()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiYpe.png)
[After I removed FIttedBox()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUnK5.png)

But as you can [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGT9U.png) even it's 100x100, the image itself is not expanded as I want

It should match the whole purple area I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is the code, but the image

[image: 1]

I'm not an image expert so I speak as a hypothesis: maybe even the images that contain only the object have a transparent box with a dimension behind it, and in your image that box was big and made your image small. I tried copying the image to a smaller box and using that fixed the size issue.

[info_card_icon2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWF0S.png)

Comment: that can be an issue, I'll try your image.

Comment: yeah! that actually works.
thanks a lot, you're definitely an image expert))

Answer (score 0):

In your image.asset give his property

```
fit: BoxFit.cover
```

Comment: I have tried and no changes. I am curious why it's not working as I tried it in a body of Scaffold without any Columns/Rows and it was working as expacted. So I can see the problem is in Row

Comment: Or you can remove the fitted box and try with boxfit.cover again

Comment: well that kind of worked... DevTools say that the image is 100x100. I will edit the post to show the problem now